How to utilize a nested object for a prepopulated Vuetify form
I have started to use typescript to try and build more consistent models which are requested and sent to my API endpoints. However, I am struggling with using these complex object types as models for my forms. My api returns a complex object which binds perfect to my type and it goes about three objects deep as shown:
export interface CertificationReview {
    mmcid: number;
    mmcid_for_display: string;
    state_details: State;
    review_details: ReviewDetails;
    policy_details: PolicyDetails;
    actuarial_firm_details: ActuarialFirm;
    certifications: Document[];
    supporting_documents: Document[];
    contract_documents: Document[];
    addendums: Document[];
    dmcp_working_documents: Document[];
    oact_documents: Document[];
    ilos_documents: Document[];
    miscellaneous_documents: Document[];
}

export interface State {
    state_id: number;
    entity_name: string;
    entity_abbreviation: string;
    program_details: Program[];
    state_contacts: User[];
}

export interface Program {
    program_dd: number;
    program_name: string;
    program_short_name: string;
}

export interface User {
    active_user: boolean | null;
    arms_user: boolean | null;
    avatar: string | null;
    email_address: string | null;
    first_name: string | null;
    internal_user_number: number | null;
    last_name: string | null;
    system_admin: boolean | null;
    username: string | null;
    work_group: number | null;
}

The CertificationReview is the parent object and the child nodes nest in the pattern shown above. So it goes 3 layers deep at most in the example shown above. So on the initial load of my component which has form data (mainly v-autocompletes, v-selects, and v-text-fields) that are preloaded with the model as shown:
  const currentReview = reactive<CertificationReview>(await certificationReviewStore.getCertificationReview(parseInt(route.params.mmcid as string)));

I am trying to use this currentReview as the model for every components so that way at the end when I hit the update button it will just send that model as json to my api endpoint. Some examples of my form items using the models above are as follows:
   <v-col cols="12" sm ="4">
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="currentReview.state_details"
      variant="outlined"
      hide-details
      color="primary"
      chips
      label="State"
      :items="stateData"
      item-title="entity_name"
      flat
      return-object
      :rules="objectRequiredRule"
      rounded
      readonly
    />
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" sm ="4">
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="currentReview.state_details.program_details"
      multiple
      variant="outlined"
      hide-details
      color="primary"
      flat
      rounded
      clearable
      chips
      label="Programs"
      :items="currentReview!.state_details ? stateData.find(item => item.state_id == currentReview!.state_details.state_id)?.program_details : []"
      item-title="program_name"
      return-object
      :rules="arrayRequiredRule"
    />
  </v-col>

Trying to develop my component in this manner causes the following error from trying to use an await inside that reactive variable declaration:
Component <Anonymous>: setup function returned a promise, but no <Suspense> boundary was found in the parent component tree. A component with async setup() must be nested in a <Suspense> in order to be rendered. 

In addition I struggle because on load these variables are null and also when i move to a different review page I refresh the data so I clear out the old before bringing in the new to kind of clean things up. This causes the issue that the components are looking for a node that doesnt exist because the parent object is null. So currentReview.state_details.program_details[0] would tripp an error if set as the model for the program auto complete. Last but not least trying to use these nested objects seems complex because the v-model or data depends on the parent nodes selection and I am struggling with how to make this work.

Ref and reactive are pretty much the same. More of a syntax thing really.

Any reason doing an await inside of a reactive or ref just breaks everything?

Because I don't think that you're supposed to call them like that. I guess it works fine with individual functions and variables, rather than stacking it all in one way. Might also just be a syntax issue tbh. Not a big deal in itself.

I was only trying to call the the axios request/ async function in the declaration because I do not want to create a fake initial object for my reactive variable. Not sure how to fix this.

The error means what it says. You can only use async components inside . You don't actually need reactive() if getCertificationReview returns store state, it would be reactive already. And if it's a state, it's a bad practice to mutate it like v-model="currentReview.state_details"

@Estus so do you recommend making a separate variable for each v-model (ie, stateDetails) and only use the currentReview to load the data into each v-model variable?

This depends on your case. The question doesn't explain the context well enough. It's not shown what getCertificationReview does. You may not need global state at all for this. But in case there's a case for it, clone form state from the store to local state and commit it back to the store on submit. Mutating the store directly as you probably tried will prevent you from reverting edited fields if necessary and also is hard to debug.

Let me pose my question better above. I will edit it. I agree I do not provide enough context.
